# React Modal covers the whole screen

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-modal

I have a react modal inside a react table cell. issue is that, it covers the whole screen. Any idea why it is happening ? This is the code snippet of a react table cell.

```
Header: '',
Cell: row => {
return (                                                        
<div>                                                             
<Modal open={this.state.open} onClose= . 
{this.onCloseModal}>                                                               
<h2>Simple centered modal</h2>                                                    
</Modal>
</div>
```

When i click a a . button,  i set the open as true,but the modal covers the whole screen, Any idea why ?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code for the modal or which library you use?

Comment: ah.my bad:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-modal

Comment: Can you show us the whole render method

Comment: Modal by definition is supposed to cover the whole page.

If you don't want cover the whole page, what you should use is a popper or a pop-over.